# incrementally rebase onto latest master

Tags: rebase, git-rebase, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

Let's say over past 8 hours, 2 PRs have merged to master. They are of medium size, not so huge, but not so small.

I'd like to incrementally rebase onto latest master. i.e., I'd like to rebase onto master as of the first PR merging, resolve conflicts, and then rebase onto latest master, as of the 2nd PR merging.

This makes merge conflicts very small.

If teams maintain a practice of creating good commit history through atomic commits, a developer could even incrementally rebase onto latest master on a per-commit basis. This makes conflicts as small as humanly possible, although you better be comfortable with rebasing, because there will be lots of tiny conflicts in comparison.

**How can I perform multiple incremental rebases onto master, in the order that PRs were merged?**

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Added question to bottom

Comment: Maybe to solve this we need to write some script that is rather involved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need first to identify the commit hashes corresponding to the points right after each PR merge into master. You can find these using the Git log.

```
master: A -- B -- C -- D -- E
                 /         /
PRs:            F         G
```

`A` to `E` are commits on `master`, `F` and `G` are the last PR commits just before merge to master, `C` is the merge-commit for the first PR merge, and `E` is the merge-commit for the second PR merge.

Here, you need `F` and `G`.

Then you can script your incremental rebases, PR by PR, using [`git rebase --onto`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase#Documentation/git-rebase.txt---ontoltnewbasegt) to transplant a range of commits from one part of the tree onto another.

A script (`incremental_rebase.sh`) could be:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# Check if at least two commit hashes are provided
if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    echo "Usage: $0 <base_branch> <commit_hash1> [<commit_hash2> ...]"
    exit 1
fi

# Base branch (usually master)
base_branch=$1

# Update the base branch with the latest changes
git fetch origin $base_branch
git switch $base_branch
git merge origin/$base_branch

# Shift off the base branch from the arguments list
shift

# Store the original branch name
original_branch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

# Initial base for the rebase operation
base_commit=$(git merge-base $original_branch $base_branch)

# Rebase incrementally for each commit hash
for commit_hash in "$@"
do
    echo "Rebasing commits up to $commit_hash onto $base_branch..."

    # Rebase the range of commits onto the base branch
    git rebase --onto $base_branch $base_commit $commit_hash

    # Check for rebase conflict
    if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
        echo "Conflict detected. Please resolve the conflict and run 'git rebase --continue'."
        exit 1
    fi

    # Update the base_commit to the current commit_hash for the next iteration
    base_commit=$commit_hash
done

# Final rebase of the remaining commits
git rebase --onto $base_branch $base_commit $original_branch

echo "Incremental rebase complete."
```

Run the script with the base branch (e.g., `master`) and the commit hashes as arguments: `./incremental_rebase.sh master commit_hash_1 commit_hash_2`.

That will update your `base_branch` (master) to the latest.
`git rebase --onto` will rebase the changes incrementally, starting from the merge base of your feature branch and the `base_branch`, up to each of the commit hashes provided.
Resolve any conflicts that arise during each rebase step, run `git rebase --continue` before proceeding to the next step after each conflict resolution.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing, and I will certain recall this next time I encounter a super massive merge conflict!